# Jquery UI accordion not working in Joomla with Shape5 template

Tags: jquery, joomla

I'm have problems with the jquery accordion not working in joomla with shape5 template.

I'm using a flexi code module for Joomla so I can put any code inside and render it. I made few divs to be rendered with Jquery in an accordion style but for some reason they don't work.

You can take a look at rbbs2012.regattalive.com ...the problem is the "leadership" module.
If I take the code from that module and put it into a html file and load it on the server the accordion works fine but inside Joomla it doesn't.

Anyone have an ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an jquery conflict on that page. 
Code written for accordian is using $.

So replace the code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#lb_effect" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      autoHeight: false
    });
   });
```

with this one

```
 var lb = jQuery.noConflict();
    lb(document).ready(function(){
    lb( "#lb_effect" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      autoHeight: false
    });
   });
```

Comment: after playing with it i got it working by including the google apis jquery ui library.